# Html links to other directories won't link correctly on Ubuntu

Tags: html, css, ubuntu, hyperlink

I have made a few simple pages and Web Apps, and they work fine on my Windows computer, but when I open them on any browser on Ubuntu, it seems like anything that is linked to in a directory that is not the main directory, the link is broken. Maybe I am missing something about relative directories. When I move any of these to the main directory, and write the link without a directory change, it works fine. What Am I missing about changing directories? Here are a couple of the parts that are not linking up when I open them.

CSS: simple enough, it displays coffee.jpg on Windows 8, but I get nothing on Ubuntu. Is Ubuntu not recognizing the directory change?

```
body {
    background-image: url('Backgrounds/coffee.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

html: here is one of many links I make that should lead to a page displaying examples of raw Javascript code. Again, Ubuntu doesn't seem to understand the directory change.

```
<a href="code/musicnotes/1.js">-JavaScript Code</a>
```

Comment: Are those local files or placed on a web server? if the latter, using Ubuntu is not the problem. Code looks fine to me anyways, although I suggest prefixing relative links with `./` to make it more clear it's relative on purpose.

Comment: It looks like I just messed up some uppercase letters. What is ./ mean? What is it for?

Comment: `.`means "current direcotry", same way as `..` means "parent direcotry". Technically, there is no reason to ever specify it. BUt to other humans, it's more clear that it's relative on purpose and not just lacking a `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In linux, the file paths and names are **case sensitive**. Unlike in Windows.
Does this help? :)

Comment: Doubt that, moving the files shouldn't solve the issue in this case. Also, for files on a server, the setting is server-side, so the local OS shouldn't matter. (for local files though, yoU're right)

Comment: Aha, thank you!! That was it! I should have known; I was so frustrated with cd not working in the terminal yesterday, and then I figured out that it was case sensitive. I should have known. Thank you!